# Is there a way to "call" a function in R?

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where lots of graphs are needed, and I have to put a source on every one of them. Is there a way to only write it once and refer to it later?

I have this:

```
plot(db)
grid.text("Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del INEGI", 0.8, 0.03,
    gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", fontface = "italic", cex = 0.7))

plot(db_2)
grid.text("Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del INEGI", 0.8, 0.03,
    gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", fontface = "italic", cex = 0.7))
```

And need something like this:

```
fuente <- grid.text("Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del INEGI", 0.8, 0.03,
    gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", fontface = "italic", cex = 0.7))

plot(db)
fuente

plot(db_2)
fuente
```

Comment: I think a way close to what you want is to save the grob, and the draw it as required (as opposed to drawing it with grid.text) e.g. `fuente <- textGrob("Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del INEGI", 0.8, 0.03, gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", fontface = "italic", cex = 0.7))}` and then call it as needed with `grid.draw(fuente)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```r
fuente <- function() {
   grid.text("Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del INEGI", 0.8, 0.03,
    gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", fontface = "italic", cex = 0.7))
}
```

? Then `fuente()` will call your function/execute your code.

If you want to be really clever, you can

```r
makeActiveBinding("fuente2", fuente, .GlobalEnv)
```

and then calling `fuente2` (without parentheses) should work (but I wouldn't advise this: it's probably too clever/not a standard idiom)

A more standard way to do this would be to make a wrapper function for your plot call:

```r
myplot <- function(x) {
   plot(x)
   grid.text(...)
}
myplot(db)
myplot(db2)
```

(this is not literal, fill in the `...` with the body of your `grid.text()` call)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to also wrap with `quote` and then use `eval`

```
fuente <- quote(grid.text("Fuente: Elaboración propia con datos del INEGI", 0.8, 0.03,
 gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", fontface = "italic", cex = 0.7)))
plot(db)
eval(fuente)
```